# Prevent Visual Studio from trying to parse typescript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Working on a project using Visual Studio as my IDE. It has an API component written in C#, and a webserver component that uses TypeScript.

I am using webpack to deal with the typescript compilation and would like to remove the Visual Studio build step from the typescript files.

Normally I wouldn't care if it was building them, but I am using Typescript > 1.8.4 which has language features that Visual Studio cannot understand which is making Visual Studio throw errors and prevent compilation. I found a workaround for this in [this github issue thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518) but I have other developers cross team who are working on this and trying to coordinate a hack to make code among them will not work.

I have also tried removing the typescript imports line from the .csproj file, but whenever I add a new ts file, it adds the line back in.

Is there a way to completely shut down the typescript compilation/parsing step in Visual Studio and prevent it from coming back?

This in in VS 2015.

Comment: VS is super agressive about this! I have an unloaded project that contains all my angular code and it's still trying to parse it! Fortunately in this case restarting VS cleared it out. I'm now using VSCode for all Angular code and VS for server side stuff.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can disable typescript compilation by editing the .csproj file to contain the following:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

That should disable all typescript compilation within VS 2015.

Comment: Do you how I can disable typescript errors in project.json based project. I am using .Net Core 1.1

Comment: No, sorry I don't off hand.

Comment: It took 5 years but you finally got that accepted answer! (sorry for the delay )

Answer (score 34):

It seems that the errors are triggered by IntelliSense and one can remove IntelliSense errors by simply filtering the list.

[image]

In case that other solutions doesn't help this is the key to clean up the error list, at least temporarily.

Comment: This extra step did it for me.

Comment: I think this got defaulted to Build + InteelliSense in an update recently - this fixed it for me!

Answer (score 24):

To disable TypeScript compilation altogether for Visual Studio, edit:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets`

(*Your path might be slightly different depending on your OS/VS version, in that case just search for `Microsoft.TypeScript.targets`*)

And add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works for .NET Core projects as well.

Comment: This file is no longer under "C:\Program Files (x86)\".  It has been moved to "C:\Program Files\" in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 16):

Sam Storie's answer is a great start and it will stop typescript errors from preventing compilation, but Visual Studio will still report the parsing errors which will prevent the ability to use the built in publishing tools.

To completely remove error reporting in ts, find all import lines in the csproj that reference typescript and set the Condition property to false, make sure to restart VS afterwards:

Example:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="false" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove / Uncheck Test Javascript Content Files from the Project filter.

[image: Filter]

Comment: what and where is that ?

Comment: It's in Error List window->Project column-> filter icon

Comment: This does not apply to solutions where the TypeScript files are mixed with C# files in a project.

Comment: Works for me! For me i got to untick the tsconfig.json